# Unable to get keys from firebase database

Tags: ios, firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

I have been pondering for the longest time in my student programmer life. I would like to know

**I added the keys using autoChildId.**

1. How to get keys from firebase database swift 2? I know how to get from Android using .getKeys()
2. My best friend, Google, taught me to use allKeys. However, my friendship is on the verge of in despair right now as I received the following msg that our relationship with .allKeys will always fail ( see image below). Haish...

[image: Evidence of our relationship status right now]

3. I need this in order to show the data from Firebase Database into my tableview cos I believe this is the issue to a empty table just like how my heart is for my project. No heart.

Here is how my firebase database looks like:

[image: My firebase database]

Here is my code:

```
func findPlaceToEat(){
    print("inside findPlaceToEat()")

    print("Plan price level")
    print(planPriceLevel)
    print("End of price level")

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    ref.child("places_detail").child("price_level").child(planPriceLevel).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock:{
        (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value?.allKeys! as? [String: AnyObject]{
            let PlaceObj = placeObj(place_name: dictionary["place_name"] as! String, place_type: dictionary["place_type"] as! String, price_range: dictionary["price_range"] as! String, vegan_type:dictionary["vegan_type"] as! String , website: dictionary["website"] as! String)
            print("Whatever")

            print(PlaceObj);
            //self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
        }, withCancelBlock: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to get key from snapshot

```
snapshot.key
```

Comment: sorry man, it doesn't work for my case man. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: it should work I checked it myself. You might not be getting any data at all. try checking if snapshot.exists()

Comment: hey man, do you happens to have any reference you could share to me? thanks a lot. @rv7284

Comment: @charlinagnes `snapshot.key` in your completion block should have the value `-K...` (see the [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDataSnapshot#key)). If it doesn't work, show the code you tried and what it *does* do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your help again sir. i got my answer for swift 2 version base on my case. I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got a workaround for my project, everyone please pray that my lecturer don't see this. :

What I did was inside the save button I retrieve the value from database and then save it back into Firebase Database.

```
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


    ref.child("hello").child("google! I need a part time job").child(planPriceLevel).observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.ChildAdded, withBlock:{
        (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
            let getPlaceObj = placeObj()

            getPlaceObj.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)
            self.PlaceObj.append(getPlaceObj)


            print("Name " ,getPlaceObj.place_name)


        }

        let place_name = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("place_name") as! String
        let place_type = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("place_type") as! String
        let price_range = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("price_range") as! String
        let vegan_type = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("vegan_type") as! String
        let website = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("website") as! String

        print(place_name, place_type, price_range, vegan_type, website)

        let savePlan : [String: AnyObject] = ["place_name":place_name, "place_type":place_type, "price_range":price_range, "vegan_type":vegan_type, "website":website]

        self.ref.child("can you place hire me as your intern? I am from Singapore!!!").child(self.user!.uid).childByAutoId().setValue(savePlan)


        }, withCancelBlock: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define query orderbykey like bellow:

```
  this.afd.list('/yourItems/', {query:{orderByKey :true}}).subscribe((elements) => {

            elements.map(element=>{
              console.log(element.$key);

            })

        });
```